# How can I use Ubuntu 12.04 to install its driver for a wireless usb adapter in a Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

How can I use an installed Ubuntu 12.04 system to install its driver *rt2800usb* (for a Ralink RT3070 net adapter), or a similar one that works, in Ubuntu 10.04? Is it possible?
Thank you

The driver's version for 12.04 is 3.2.0-23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the device and in a terminal, do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/network_drivers.rules
```

Add one long line:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="07d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="3c16", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -qba rt2870sta"
```

Caps, brackets, punctuation, etc. are crucial. Proofread twice, save and close gedit.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/network_drivers.conf
```

Add one long single line:

```
install rt2870sta /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install rt2870sta $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/echo "07d1 3c16" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2870/new_id
```

Proofread twice, save and close gedit. Insert the device. If it doesn't start immediately, you might have to do:

```
sudo modprobe rt2870sta
```